# totp verificaton failing in signup method when user try to enter otp received in mail

Tags: javascript, express, totp

I require some help here I am creating a signup method with a feature where user is authenticated via otp send in mail to verify that the email entered by user belongs to him.
Now the problem here is that the otp generated via totp.Let me explain the flow the user calls sendOTP function and use that to signup with required fields. I was just testing the code whether the otp generated can be verifiable in signup or not which is not working as expected

```
const totp = require('otplib').totp
const ErrorHandler = require('../util/errorHandler')
const OTP = require('../model/OTP')
const User = require('../model/User')
const Profile = require('../model/Profile')

exports.sendOTP = async(req, res, next) => {
    const {email} = req.body;
    if(!email){
        return next(new ErrorHandler("All fields are required", 400));
    }
    const secret = process.env.OTP_SECRET
    const expiresAt = new Date();
    expiresAt.setMinutes(expiresAt.getMinutes() + 5);
    var token = totp.generate(secret, expiresAt);
    await OTP.create({
        email,
        otp: token,
    })
    return res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        message: "OTP sent successfully",
        token
    })

}


exports.signUp = async(req, res, next) =>{
    const {
        firstName,
        lastName,
        email,
        password,
        confirmPassword,
        accountType,
        contactNumber,
        otp
        
    } = req.body;
    if (!firstName || !lastName || !email || !password || !confirmPassword) {
        return next(new ErrorHandler('Please fill all the details', 400))
    }
    if(password !== confirmPassword){
        return next(new ErrorHandler("Password and Confirm Password do not match. Please try again.", 400));
    }
    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email });
    if(existingUser){
        return next(new ErrorHandler("User already exists. Please sign in to continue.", 400));
    }
    const data = await OTP.findOne({email})
    const token = data.otp
   
    const secret = process.env.OTP_SECRET


    if(totp.check(otp, secret)){
        return res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            message: 'Signed up successfully'
        })
    }else{
        return res.status(400).json({
            success: false,
            message: 'Invalid OTP'
        })


    }
const express = require('express')
const router =express.Router();

const asyncHandler = require('../util/asyncHandler')


const {sendOTP, signUp} = require('../controller/auth')
router.get('/sendOTP', asyncHandler(sendOTP))
router.post('/signup', asyncHandler(signUp))
module.exports = router;

}
```

Then I tried to whether the generated otp is verifiable by feching it from database

```
 const data = await OTP.findOne({email})
    const token = data.otp
    if(otp !== token){
        return next(new ErrorHandler("Invalid otp", 400));
    }
    const secret = process.env.OTP_SECRET


    if(totp.check(token, secret)){
        return res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            message: 'Signed up successfully'
        })
    }else{
        return res.status(400).json({
            success: false,
            message: 'Invalid OTP'
        })
    }
```

It still returns false which should have returned true instead